# Where clause not working

Tags: where-clause, google-sheets

`=QUERY('Sheet8'!A:Z;"select A, B where 'Year' = 2016")`
I have this query and I wanted to make the year part dynamic so I tried this
`=QUERY('Sheet8'!A:Z;"select A, B where 'Year' = year(now())+4")`
But that didn't work so even tried saving the values in cells and the referencing them in the were clause like `where 'Year' = Sheet!B1` but that didn't work either. How can I create a where statement that looks performs an operation before doing the comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `year()` function in the QUERY select clause is a [scalar function](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#scalar_functions) that must reference one of the columns. So if the column of dates is in column A, you would use `where year(A) =` etc.

To make it dynamic, it is best (IMO) to concatenate a value generated from spreadsheet functions (rather than the select clause, which doesn't seem to generate according to the spreadsheet time zone). So something like:

`=QUERY('Sheet8'!A:Z;"select A, B where year(A) = "&(YEAR(NOW())+4))`

Comment: This has helped (I'm getting no errors), but its still not finding any valid matches in the year column.  I don't have a lot control over how that column is formatted as and I'm not sure exactly if it is string, number, etc (it was imported from another data source).  Trying to convert it to year gives me an error so does trying `text(N,"")`

Comment: Generally date-like entries that have not been converted successfully to a numerical date will be left-aligned, but you can also test in a spare cell with eg `=ISNUMBER(A2)` to see if it's a number. If not, they are text strings, in which case you might want to try a regex match instead: `=QUERY('Sheet8'!A:Z;"select A, B where A matches '.*"&(YEAR(NOW())+4)&".*'")`

Comment: But if some in the column are numbers and some are text strings, you will need a further workaround to convert them all to strings first.

Comment: Thanks the regex worked. What I wanted to do I was sure was pretty simple, but I had a hard time finding anything helpful in the docs (not to mention there error message aren't always helpful).  Plus I am used to programming languages where the syntax makes more sense; to me at least.